# Soft vs Hard word wrap in Emacs

Tags: wrapping

There are (in my mind) two types of word wrapping:

- Hard : Actually edit the file to have lines of a maximum length
- Soft : Just wrap in the editor, but the underlying file still has long lines.

I can't figure out how to make Emacs do these two different types of word wrapping (most people just talk about "word wrap", without distinguishing which they are talking about).

Comment: Emacs uses the term "fill" for hard wrapping.

Comment: `C-h r` to visit the Emacs manual. Then `i wrap TAB RET`. That completes `wrap` to `wrapping` and then visits the part of the manual (node [Continuation Lines](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Continuation-Lines.html)) that talks about this. In that node you also find a link to node [Visual Line Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html), which talks about your "soft" wrapping.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Emacs uses `visual-line-mode` for the soft-wrap and `auto-fill-mode` (and/or `refill-mode`) for the hard-wrap. See [What is the difference between refill-mode and auto-fill-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47587/19069) for the difference between the two.